# What does <var name="ROMAN"> mean in xsl

Tags: xslt

I am really facing a strange problem. ROMAN characters are not displaying at all in mozilla and google chrome except on IE8(not in IE10 as well).

The code was written using xsl transformations. and i am unable to find what does 
`<var name="ROMAN">` is? This is the exact text when i see the html source.

Even the same code is written in xsl.

Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Comment: No, `<var>` doesn't mean anything to XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

`<var>` is an HTML element that means "This is a variable". It will typically cause the contained text to be rendered in italic. It doesn't mean anything special to XSLT, it's just like any other HTML element name. name="ROMAN" is just like the name attribute of any other HTML element, it can be used in Javascript to address the relevant element node in the page. It doesn't change the rendition of the element, unless perhaps there is some stylesheet somewhere that recognizes name="ROMAN" and associates it with a display style.

I think you've got an HTML question, not an XSLT question. There's something wrong with your HTML, and we don't know what, because you haven't given enough information.